# How to insert a formula with VBA that contains a number varibleex

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula that I'm trying to insert in cell D8. The value is in cell M15, so I'm trying to take that value and make the formula (value in M15 - D12). I have the following code, but I keep getting an error (400 error). Can someone help figure this out?

```
Dim chargeinput As Worksheet
Set chargeinput = model.Worksheets("Charge Input")

Dim i As Long
i = bdws.Range("M15").Value   'dbws is a worksheet set as a variable, it changes 
                               but the value is always in M15


chargeinput.Range("D8").Formula = "=i-" & D12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula construction is using *i* as something the worksheet recognizes; concatenate it into the formula. D12 should be D12 on the *Charge Input* worksheet.

```
chargeinput.Range("D8").Formula = "=" & i & "-D12"
'does i have to be there?
'is it bdws or dbws? Your sample is confusing
chargeinput.Range("D8").Formula = "='" & bdws.name & "'!M15-D12"
```